# How to printing only directories with awk command

Tags: regex, bash, awk, getdirectories

I want to print only directories by using *awk* command. I don't want to print current and parent directories so I have created an appropriate regex match:

```
ls -la | awk '$1 ~ /[d].*/ && $9 !~ /^\.$/ && $9 !~ /^\.\.$/   { print $1"\t"$9 } '
```

The code works correctly but I wanted to make it more readable, like this:

```
ls -la | awk '$1 ~ /[d].*/ && $9 !~ /^\.{1,2}$/    { print $1"\t"$9 } '
```

Unfortunately, the second match doesn't work.

How should it be defined to match one or two *dot*s?

Comment: Why not just use `ls -lA` which will exclude the entries for `.` and `..`?

Comment: Yes, it is alway better to use a commands that are so far implemented but you have to know about them... Thanks for response. I will make use of your proposition but I am still wondering how my regex should be properly defined to achieved its objective.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, I will make use of your hint :)

The answer for my question is


`ls -lA| awk  '$1 ~ /[d].*/ {print $1"\t"$9}'`

Answer (score 0):

Your second example works just fine for me:

```
$ /bin/ls -la | awk '$1 ~ /[d].*/ && $9 !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ {print $1"\t"$9}'
drwxr-xr-x  .git
drwxr-xr-x  .idea
drwxr-xr-x  data
drwxr-xr-x  src
```

When I was looking at it at first, it wasn't working for me either because I have 'ls' aliases to 'ls -lF' which meant that the current directory was being listed as "./" and the parent was "../" which was failing to match the regex because the '/' was anchored at the end of the line (the '$' in your regex). I wonder if you had a similar problem.

Comment: Combination of ls -lF failed too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the awk command in Solaris, please replace awk by `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

```
ls -la | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '$1 ~ /[d].*/ && $9 !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ {print $1"\t"$9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd example doesn't work because older awk (non-gnu) awk version don't support regex number pattern like this:

```
/\.{1,2}/
```

However just to get directory list you shouldn't parse ls`s output.

**EDIT:** To print hidden directories but avoid `.` and `..` use this:

You can use:

```
printf "%s\n" */ .*[!.]*/
```

Keep in mind file/directory names with newline in them are problematic.

Comment: From command awk --version, I know that I a using GNU Awk 3.1.8, so according to your information everything should work properly :)

Your second hint doesn't match hidden directories :/

Comment: see updated answer OR else try: `printf "%s\n" */ .*/` to print hidden directories also.

Comment: But using `printf "%s\n" */ .*/` will print "." and ".." directories, what I want to avoid.

Comment: You are stubborn :) Thanks for all your answers :)

Comment: Well important thing is getting your problem solved. Did you get desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, which does not include hawk but works well:

```
ls -ld */
```

or even better

```
ls -1 -d */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an astarisk *

```
ls -la | awk '$1 ~ /[d].*/ && $9 !~ /^\.*$/ {print $1"\t"$9}'
```